# Docusign: Signatures missing in completed document

Tags: docusignapi, signatures

I am trying to add 2 signer tabs from code for a document and send. I am able to see the signatures tabs properly where they are expected. After the document signed by both signers, when i open the completed document, the signatures are missing. The pdf also shows an error message saying pdf has errors.

Here is my xml. Can you please help:

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
 <emailSubject>API Call for adding signature request to document and sending</emailSubject>
<status>sent</status>
            <documents>
            <document>
             <name> documentName  </name>
                <documentId>1</documentId>
                <order>1</order>
            </document>
            </documents>
            <recipients>
            <signers>
            <signer>
                <email> custEmail    </email>
                <name> recipientNameCust  </name>
                 <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                <routingOrder>1</routingOrder>
            <tabs> 

            <signHereTabs>
            <signHere>
               <anchorString>SIGNED on behalf of the Customer</anchorString>
               <anchorXOffset>10</anchorXOffset>
               <anchorYOffset>50</anchorYOffset>
               <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>false</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
               <anchorUnits>Pixels</anchorUnits>
               <documentId>1</documentId>
               <recipientId>1</recipientId>
               <tabLabel>Sign Here1</tabLabel>
               <name>SignHere1</name>
            </signHere>
                   </signHereTabs>
            </tabs>
            </signer>

            <signer>
                <email> receipientEmail    </email>
                <name> recipientNameTotal  </name>
                <recipientId>2</recipientId>
                <routingOrder>2</routingOrder>
            <tabs> 

            <signHereTabs>
            <signHere>
               <anchorString>SIGNED on behalf of Total Gas</anchorString>
               <anchorXOffset>10</anchorXOffset>
               <anchorYOffset>50</anchorYOffset>
               <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>false</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
               <anchorUnits>Pixels</anchorUnits>
               <documentId>1</documentId>
               <recipientId>2</recipientId>
               <tabLabel>Sign Here2</tabLabel>
               <name>SignHere2</name>
            </signHere>
                   </signHereTabs>
            </tabs>
            </signer>
            </signers>
            </recipients> </envelopeDefinition>
```

Comment: To add to Kim's suggestion, what you have presented will NOT be enough for support, you will want the following: 1. Can you reproduce this error? 2. Do you have a low level HTTP trace of the request and response ( the above is only the body) 3. EnvelopeID(s) of envelope(s) you have the issue(s) with

Answer (score 1):

You should contact DocuSign support.  If the signers are signing and submitting documents, you should see the signatures in the completed document.